# Is it possible to create ng-grid's dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

as part of one of my web projects I need multiple instances of ng-grid in a same app, being the user able to create dynamically as many grids as needed (Think of usual "Add New Grid..") button.
I've gone through the docs and implemented a prototype but I've found that the setup for the grid includes the hardcoded name of the variable containing the data, for example:

in the  angular .js controller,

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
```

I've tried using a variable instead, for example:

```
var mychart = [{...}, {...}];   // data rows
$scope.gridOptions = { data: $scope.mychart };
```

and

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="{{gridOptions}}">
```

but without success. All the examples I've found on the web use only one table so my question remains unanswered.
Any idea of how this could be resolved or is a major limitation of this grid system?
Thanks!

Comment: `{{gridOptions}}` doesn't do what you think it does. You can create a new scope for each grid instead.

Comment: so what does it do instead? Could you explain a little better the thing about creating a new scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, when you find yourself needing an arbitrary number of objects, you should think about putting them in a collection rather than giving them individual names.  I've updated wayne's jsfiddle to use arrays and ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/Th47J/

Make a grid for each option:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in gridOptions" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="option"></div>
```

Obviously if these are being created on the fly, you'll need to update the gridOptions array programmatically rather than having everything hard-coded.  But if the data source is the only thing that is changing that's very easy.

Comment: Great.  I wasn't sure it would work, but so often Angular just does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally managed to do this. The key is that the data reference (myData[] in this case) can be generated dynamically (myData + '[' + myData.length + ']' for example), each time a new tab is added.
Of course it's up to you to keep sync between the tabs and the myData length.

The HTML:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" id="{{tab.id}}">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="{{tab.ref}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular part:

```
$scope.tabs = [
        {id: 0, title: 'a', contentId: '#0', data: 'lorem 1', ref:{data: 'myData[0]'}},
        {id: 1, title: 'b', contentId: '#1', data: 'lorem 2', ref:{data: 'myData[1]'}},
        {id: 2, title: 'c', contentId: '#2', data: 'lorem 3', ref:{data: 'myData[2]'}}
    ];

$scope.myData = [[
        {name: "ryan1", surn: "smith1", address:"main square 1", phone:"000000001"},
        {name: "ryan1", surn: "smith1", address:"main square 1", phone:"000000001"},
        ],
        [{name: "ryan2", surn: "smith2", address:"main square 2", phone:"000000002"},
         {name: "ryan2", surn: "smith2", address:"main square 2", phone:"000000002"},
        ],
        [{name: "ryan3", surn: "smith3", address:"main square 3", phone:"000000003"},
         {name: "ryan3", surn: "smith3", address:"main square 3", phone:"000000003"},
        ],
];
```